# Simulating data and C stack usage

Tags: r

I'm trying to simulate some data and use the `step` function.  First, I generate a 1000 X 101 dimensional data frame.

```
library(broom)

    data_func <- function(n=1000*101) {
      data <- matrix(rnorm(n),1000,101)
      data.frame(data)
    }
```

Then I create a function that uses `step` to select a model by forward stepwise selection and extracts the p-value for the F-test of the selected model.

```
step <- function(d) {
  sfit <- step(lm(X1 ~.,data=d))
  glance(sfit)$p.value
}
```

I want to extract the p-values from a 100 repetitions of this simulation, so I have:

```
pvalues_step <- raply(100,step(data_func()))
```

But I get:

```
Error: C stack usage  7969512 is too close to the limit
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You override the function `step` from `package:stats`. You might end up in recursion. Try using a different name for your custom `step` function.

Comment: That’s embarrassing! That seems to have fixed the problem, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the problem was solved in the comments I would like to explain what was going on in more detail:

In R it is possible to give custom functions the name of build-in functions or those from other packages without being warned:

```
mean <- function(x) {print("I am mean")}

> mean(5)
[1] I am mean
```

In your case you overwrite the definition of `step` from `package:stats`. In addition, you call `step` inside `step`. This is called recursion. Recursion in R is explained for example [here](https://www.programiz.com/r-programming/recursion).

Depending on the amount of data and the level of recursion this may end up with an (almost) full stack.